# Помогите с кодом Python

Tags: python

Помогите написать строчку чтобы он писал: "введите имя", и если вы введёте имя то там будет написано `Имя которое пользователь ввёл вы зарегистрировались` и потом `Имя которое пользователь ввёл и добро пожаловать`

Вот код:

```
off = int(input("Введите пароль: ")) 
if off == 123456:
    print("Пароль слишком слабый введите другой!")
elif off == 123456789:
     print("Пароль слишком слабый введите другой!")
elif off == 1111111:
    print("Пароль слишком слабый введите другой!")
elif off == 123:
    print("Пароль слишком слабый введите другой!")
elif off == 1:
     print("Пароль слишком слабый введите другой!")
else:
    print("Пароль принят!")
```

Comment: почитайте 'форматирование строк питон'  и 'регулярные выражения питон'

Comment: Ваш код не имеет никакой связи с вашей задачей.

Comment: Здравствуйте на Stack Overflow на русском! **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.** Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи**. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу. **Не хватит привлечь какой-нибудь код.**

Comment: MarinanD, а как сделать чтобы имело связь

Comment: Как доп задание: почитайте про работу со списками в питоне

Comment: @D1M4IKGAMECHANNEL начать решать задачу самостоятельно.

Comment: *«...а как сделать чтобы имело связь»* - Я не знаю, я не специалист на такие вопросы.

Answer (score 0):

```
name=input('Введите имя: ')
print(f'{name}, Вы зарегистрировались!')
print(f'{name}, добро пожаловать!')
```